# jqGrid Search raises error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchrules' of undfined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

When I switched the jqGrid to use the advanced search - it seems to work fine, except it pops up with the above error  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchrules' of undfined" in Chrome when you hit the find button. Weirdly in Firefox the error is: "TypeError: g is undefined".

If I just click ok to the error, the page posts back to my MVC controller just fine. I just want the error to go - any ideas?
Here is the grid code:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Audit/GridData/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Date', 'Username', 'ObjectName', 'Event', 'Module'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 100, align: 'left', searchrules: { required: true }, search: true },
      { name: 'Date', index: 'DateStamp', width: 100, align: 'left', searchrules: { required: true }, search: true },
      { name: 'Username', index: 'Username', width: 200, align: 'left', searchrules: { required: true }, search: true },
      { name: 'ObjectName', index: 'ObjectType', width: 200, align: 'left', searchrules: { required: true }, search: true },
      { name: 'Event', index: 'Event', width: 120, align: 'left', searchrules: { required: true }, search: true },
      { name: 'Module', index: 'Module', width: 120, align: 'left', searchrules: { required: true }, search: true}],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            postData: {
                filters: '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"invdate","op":"gt","data":"2007-09-06"},{"field":"invdate","op":"lt","data":"2007-10-04"},{"field":"name","op":"bw","data":"test"}]}'
            },
            pgbuttons: true,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/redmond/images/',
            caption: 'Audits'
        }).navGrid('#pager', { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "Search" }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'cn', 'gt', 'lt'] });
```

Thanks

Comment: Just noticed that this only applies if I search with Id. If I don't search by Id but other columns, all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use very strange value of the `postData.filters`. It contains the rules for `invdate` and `name` fields which are not exist in the grid. I suppose that correct data will be something like

```
postData: {
    filters: '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[' +
        '{"field":"DateStamp","op":"gt","data":"2007-09-06"},' +
        '{"field":"DateStamp","op":"lt","data":"2007-10-04"},' +
        '{"field":"Username","op":"bw","data":"test"}]}'
}
```

In any way you should use the values from the `index` properties of the `colModel` which you use.

Additionally you should remove [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options) option `imgpath` which will be just ignored by jqGrid having version higher as 3.4.x.

Comment: Perfect! That works fine (once your typo of "DateStampe" was removed). This is my first time using jqGrid... thanks for your help